# Why can't I see my auto generated table in the SQL Server diagram table choice?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I created an ASP.NET MVC 4 application and used Entity Framework 6 and asp.net identity  in it ....

I successfully added a few tables and it is working perfectly.

But when I'm adding the table in the diagram in my SQL Server 2012 Management Studio (I'm using Visual Studio 2012) I only see the `userprofile` table that is generated by mvc, I can only see the tables I have created and not the tables auto generated by the framework

The following tables are missing in the diagram menu:

- webpages_Membership
- webpages_OAuthMembership
- webpages_Roles
- webpages_UsersInRoles

I know that those tables are only generated when you click on the register button on the default layout of mvc ..... don't know if it the has caused the error or not ....

I can see the tables in SQL Server 2012 Management Studio but not in the table choice of the diagram .... why? I would like to understand those table with those diagram :)

Thanks for any help :D

Comment: Do the tables exist, but not on your diagram?

Comment: lol nah man i find the error -_- i just didnt refreshed the table ...

Answer (score 0):

OK i got the responce lol ..... cause those table is creataed only when i register somone ... the diagram got only the other table that is created at the start of the programme .... si i just needed in fact to refreshing the diagram table choice! haha yeah hope i can help some one with this!